# Inserir dados no mysql, em um campo do tipo timestamp

Tags: mysql, timestamp

Como insiro uma informação em um campo desse tipo? O nome do campo é duração, gostaria de um exemplo..

Comment: Sera que isso te ajuda? da uma olha. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092303/how-to-insert-custom-date-into-mysql-timestamp-field][1]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Duas sintaxes:

```
INSERT INTO meubanco.minhatabela ( duracao ) VALUES ( '2016-04-29 00:00:00' )
```

Ou

```
INSERT INTO meubanco.minhatabela SET duracao = '2016-04-29 00:00:00'
```

(espero que seu campo seja `duracao`, e não `duração`, para evitar problemas)

O importante é passar a data como *string*, no formato `ano-mes-dia hora:minuto:segundo.centesimos`

Idealmente você vai usar 4 algarismos para o ano, e 2 para todos os outros campos, mas se passar em outro formato, em boa parte dos casos o MySQL faz um *best guess* e arredonda valores ou expande conforme necessário.

Algumas observações:

- Anos com dois dígitos tem a data-base em 1970. Assim, valores de `00` a `69` são convertidos para `2000` a `2069`, e valores de `70` a `99` para o intervalo `1970` a `1999` respectivamente.
- Para inserir o momento corrente, de acordo com o servidor do DB, você pode usar `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` ou `NOW()`;
- Caso sua coluna seja a primeira `TIMESTAMP` da tabela, por padrão o MySQL insere o *timestamp* atual se o campo for omitido, ou se for fornecido explicitamente `NULL` e a coluna especificada como `NOT NULL`;
- Ao inserir campos com a *timezone* do MySQL configurada para algo que não seja UTC, há uma conversão interna. Portanto, se inserir uma data e mudar o *timezone*, a data retornada será diferente (sempre será relativa ao UTC).

Mais detalhes no manual (em inglês):

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html

### Inserindo datas no formato DD/MM/AAAA

O ideal é que uma aplicação forneça as datas para o MySQL já no formato certo, para evitar conversões, mas se precisar de uma pré-conversão para inserção, pode fazer isso:

```
INSERT INTO meubanco.minhatabela ( duracao ) VALUES (
   STR_TO_DATE('29/04/2016','%d/%m/%Y')
)
```

Da mesma forma, para incluir a hora:

```
INSERT INTO meubanco.minhatabela ( duracao ) VALUES (
   STR_TO_DATE('29/04/2016 13:49:20','%d/%m/%Y h:%i:%s')
)
```

Mais detalhes dos campos e outras funções de conversão no manual:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date